# C++ Cannot call constructor directly in small example

Tags: c++, constructor

I was wondering, why I cannot call a constructor. Even this small example fails to compile with the message:

```
Klassentest.cpp:24:27: error: cannot call constructor 'Sampleclass::Sampleclass' directly [-fpermissive]
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Sampleclass
{
   public:
    Sampleclass();
};

Sampleclass::Sampleclass(){

}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    Sampleclass::Sampleclass() *qs = new Sampleclass::Sampleclass();
    return 0;
}
```

I used the Cygwin g++ compiler in version 4.9.3-1.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you using `new`? Also, you can't directly call a constructor in C++.

Comment: It's just C++... constructors are not regular functions. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079486/difference-between-constructor-calls-with-and-without/33079632) question and answers

Comment: I need to have a object on the heap, not the stack. This is just one small example where I also have the problem.

Answer (score 9):

```
Sampleclass::Sampleclass() *qs = new Sampleclass::Sampleclass();
```

is wrong. `Sampleclass` is a **type** while `Sampleclass::Sampleclass` is a **constructor**. Since the correct syntax is

```
type identifier = new type();
```

you need to specify the **type** here.

Therefore, use

```
Sampleclass *qs = new Sampleclass();
```

instead.

---

Notes:

- If you didn't know: since C++11 you can simply do

  ```
  Sampleclass() = default;
  ```

  in the class definition and the default constructor will be defined.

Comment: Even better, use 'Sampleclass *qs = new Sampleclass();''

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can't call ctor directly.

From the standard, [class.ctor/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#2)

> Because constructors do not have names, they are never found during name lookup;

You might want

```
Sampleclass *qs = new Sampleclass;
```

Then the ctor will be called.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Sampleclass
{
public:
    Sampleclass();
};

Sampleclass::Sampleclass(){

}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    Sampleclass *qs = new Sampleclass::Sampleclass();
    return 0;
}
```

You tried to reference the constructor as a type when instantiating your class.

Answer (score 0):

All answers containing `new` are bad style in modern c++. In a similar small example, the following worked for me (in C17):

```
Sampleclass sc = Sampleclass();
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove resolution operator, I have an issue that `Person::Person()` in child class and an error `[Error] cannot call constructor 'Student::Person' directly [-fpermissive]`
but after remove resolution operator solve this error

Comment: How does this answer the question or improve the other answers?